# Whereabouts of Odin's spear, Gungnir, after the events of Thor: Ragnarok

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok, thor-the-dark-world

In *Thor: Ragnarok* we see that Loki was on Asgard impersonating Odin since *Thor: The Dark World* (*post credits scene*) while he put Odin in a house for the elderly in New York on Earth.

Odin did leave the house and vanishes (or *dies*, if you'd prefer the term) allowing Hela to escape Hel leading to all the events of *Thor: Ragnarok*.

Since Loki is shown to be in possession of Odin's spear (Gungnir) in the post credits scene of *Thor: The Dark World*, it can be assumed that Gungnir was on Asgard.

[image: Loki on the throne with Gungnir]
 <sub>*Thor: The Dark World*</sub>

During the final fight between Thor and Hela in *Thor: Ragnarok*, Thor is seen to be sitting on Asgard's throne holding Gungnir. But after this fight, it is nowhere to be seen.

[image: Thor on the throne with Gungnir]
 <sub>*Thor: Ragnarok*</sub>

I cannot be sure if these two appearances of Gungnir (after Odin's death/imprisonment) were actually the real one and not fake (after all, Asgardians love their secrets).

However, assuming that it was the real spear of Odin, was the whereabouts of Gungnir revealed? Looking for all types of answers (in-universe, comments by the writers in interviews etc.)

***PS***: Not a dupe of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182500/what-happened-to-odins-treasures-after-ragnarok-destroyed-asgard) as it asks about his treasures (like the Eternal Flame, fake Infinity Gauntlet, Tesseract) and not about Odin's spear.

Comment: If I could venture a guess, I'd say it was left behind in Asgard and hence destroyed.

Answer (score 15):

Thor is seen holding Gungnir in *Thor: Ragnarok* as you state in the question and he uses it in the initial dual against Hela in the Throne Room. You can see the full scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mv3-G1k8VFY) and the relevant gif is below:

[image: Gif of fight between Thor and Hela with Gungnir]

Watch the end of the gif carefully as Hela throws Thor and Gungnir away, she disarms him at the same time and we don't see Gungnir again. Presumably the spear just stayed in the throne room from this point onwards, Thor had no need for it anymore as he had awakened his true power and of course Hela didn't want it so it would have just stayed there.

Presumably it was then destroyed in Ragnarok by Surtur as not much could really have survived that explosion.

But was it the real one? It does *seem* to be the real one. It appeared to be able to summon Hela to the Throne Room properly and was clearly more than just a spear as we see it glowing in the fight. I think barring any contradictory evidence we can assume that is was indeed Gungnir.